# Custom shape cutouts of a video using Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, video-processing

I wish to use Python to show a cutout in a certain shape of one video overlaid on top of another video. The invisible parts of the overlaid video should be translucent, so the 'background' video can be seen in those parts. The issue here is that the location of the overlay is dynamic, while the shape remains the same. This means I cannot simply preprocess the videos.

I was thinking to take stills from the overlaid video at runtime, cut out the overlay and superimpose it on the background video in the right location. This would have to be done at a high frequency (30 fps+, probably).

As an example:

I would want the red cutout of this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvWPx.jpg

to appear on top of another image

The Python Image Library (PIL) seems to be able to crop images easily, but only in rectangles and not in a custom shape. I could probably add rectangles together to create a custom shape, but I was hoping there would be an easier way. Maybe I'm overlooking things.

So my question is: What would be the easiest way to do the cut-out? I'm also open to other suggestions for approaches. Ideally, I would use a dynamically positioned translucent video mask partially obscuring the background video with parts of the overlaid video but I'm not sure if this is at all possible.

Comment: How do you define the cutout that you want to overlay? Do you have it in an image mask? Also, why can't you preprocess the video? You still have to define what the overlay is at each timestep.

Comment: The shape of the cutout to be overlaid is defined beforehand and does not change during the video. 

Maybe it helps if I explain in more detail what I'm trying to do. I want to simulate 'filling in' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filling-in) of blind spots of those suffering from visual field loss. To do this, I want to project parts of one video on top of the other, in the location of the blind spots. The shape of the blind spots does not change, but the location does. I use eye tracking devices to track gaze location and wish to project the blind spots relative to that location.

Comment: To clarify, the shape of the cutout depends on the shape of the visual field loss experienced a person.

Comment: No it all makes sense - so is your question about how to do the video stitching, how to do the image stitching, how to align the two videos, etc. Which part of the process are you asking about?

Comment: I've updated the original question. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Still not clear. So you have an image mask (your "cut-out"), and you have a frame from the original image. Is your question how you overlay those two?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make this more clear, since I'm not sure where to start. I was hoping for some suggestions for starting points. How to create the image mask as you call it, for example.

Comment: So the place to start is to get to the point where you have a video frame saved in a variable `frame` and a mask saved in a variable `mask`. OpenCV is a pretty general tool that can help you get frames out of a video. For the `mask`, i.e. the cutout, do you have any code that computes it given a frame?